# What does "Rebirth of Slick" mean when it quotes "On the Subway"?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, intertextuality, the-last-poets, digable-planets

Digable Planets' *Rebirth of Slick (Cool Like That)* ("Reachin' (A New Refutation of Time and Space)," 1993, track 06, released as a single in 1992) ([genius.com link](https://genius.com/Digable-planets-rebirth-of-slick-cool-like-dat-lyrics)) quotes the "blink blink" passages from *On the Subway* ("The Last Poets," 1970, track 02) ([genius.com link](https://genius.com/The-last-poets-on-the-subway-lyrics)), but in a radically different context.

What do the "blink blink/think think" lines in *Rebirth of Slick* signify independent of their reference to *On the Subway*, when taken solely as lines in Digable Planets' own work?

How does *Rebirth of Slick's* quotation of *On the Subway* transform the meaning of the quoted text? Are Digable Planets calling attention to some relationship between themselves (or their work) and The Last Poets (or *their* work)?